# If $A,B\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ s.t. $AB=I$ then $BA=I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I want to prove that if $A,B\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ are s.t. $AB=I$ then also $BA=I$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix).

$$AB=I\implies BABA=BA\implies (BA)^2-BA=0\implies BA(BA-I)=0.$$

How can I conclude from here ? I know that $CD=0\not\Rightarrow C=0$ or $D=0$. So I can't continue. I also thought to do :
$$BA(BA-I)=0\implies ABA(BA-I)=0\underset{AB=I}{\implies} A(BA-I)=0,$$
but it's not conclusive. Any idea ?

**Edited**

I can't use determinant.

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides: What do you mean ? I have a theorem that say $A$ invertible at left $\iff$ $A$ invertible at right $\iff$ $A$ invertible both side.

Comment: @Peter Yes, but nowhere in the proposition is it assumed that $A$ and $B$ are non-singular (invertible).

Comment: @SeanRoberson: Do you know singular matrix s.t. $AB=I$ ?

Comment: Since $AB=I$, then $\det A \det B = 1$ and therefore $A$ is not singular.

Comment: Try multiplying by $A^{-1}$ both sides of the last equation.

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides: I can't use det(A). I have to prove it algebraically. Moreover, $A^{-1}$ a priori not exist. I need an algebraic proof.

Comment: You should tell us what we can use.